# Linking problems with dlib: recompile with -fPIC

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors, ros, dlib

I would like to use [this](https://github.com/severin-lemaignan/gazr) ROS package which relies on [dlib](http://dlib.net/). I compile with `catkin build`, but I get this error in linking I guess:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libdlib.a(threads_kernel_shared.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_ZN4dlib21threads_kernel_shared14thread_starterEPv' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/alberto/tiago_dual_public_ws/devel/.private/gazr/lib/libgazr.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/gazr.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have installed dlib using `sudo apt-get install libdlib-dev` on my Ubuntu 18.05 (ROS Melodic) machine. How can I solve this problem? Documentation of dlib and the repo instruction does not help me a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding `-mcmodel=large` compilation flag.

Comment: Where? This is what I get with  `catkin build gazr -mcmodel=large` 
`usage: catkin [-h] [-a] [--test-colors] [--version]
              [--force-color | --no-color]
              [build | clean | config | create | env | init | list | locate | profile]
              ...
catkin: error: unrecognized arguments: -mcmodel=large
`

Comment: I'm not really familiar with catkin. A dirty way might be to edit a make file and add this parameter there. This parameter should be passed to a compiler (`CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` in CMake).

Comment: Ok, thank you. I tried to add `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-mcmodel=large" )` in the CMakeLists, but nothing changes.

Comment: UPDATE: I have been able to compile by modifing on the CMakelists this line: `target_link_libraries(gazr dlib ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})`

Comment: In general, there's a set_target_properties(target PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "<flags here>") that you should include & set for each target you produce. Also, if you found your solution, you can provide an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 possible solution to the problem.

1. Installing dlib with `sudo apt-get install libdlib-dev`

In this case you should link dlib to your library target like `target_link_libraries(gazr dlib ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})`

Rememberto use `find_package(dlib REQUIRED)`

2. Installing dlib from source

It's also possible to use directly the dlib [source file](http://dlib.net/compile.html). In this case you need to add the dlib source directory to the project using `add_subdirectory(your_path/dlib dlib)` and add it to the library `target_link_libraries(gazr dlib ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})`.

*ATTENTION*: In this case you shall not use `find_package(dlib REQUIRED)`

Hope this is helpful!